# Transforming QML/SLD in XML with QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, style, xml, qml

I have a bunch of .qml and .sld files. I want to convert them to .xml, but I still haven't found a proper way to do it.

Does anyone know any plugin or website that I can do this conversion?

Comment: sld is xml, is there some reason you want to do this?

Comment: I want to make a pull request to a community repository. They only accept xml files. But in the end, I found out how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert `.qml` or `.sld` files, all you need to do is:

1 - Import the `.qml` or `.sld` to the layers

2 - Look for the **Create style database from project** function in the toolbox

3 - Put a name in the output file

This is going to save your `.qml` or `.sld` to a `.xml` file.

---

If you have `.lyr`, I recommend seeking help from a ArcGis Users.

If you have `.style` files, you can use **SLYR** plugin to convert it.

If you have `.lyrx`, use this [website](https://mindthemap.info/util/index.html) to convert to `.qml`

Answer (score 0):

You can export `.xml` styles using the [style manager](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/style_manager.html). This, however, only allows you to save symbologies and labels, not attribute forms etc.

Comment: Hey, Erik! So, I kinda want to do the opposite. I have the `.qml` and `.sld` files. I want to transform them to `.xml` and then import via style manager

Comment: So... add layers, use the `.qml` on them and then export them to `.xml`?

Comment: I tried like this. But there's no option to export to `.xml`. Only `.qlr`, `.qml`, and `.sld`. I'm gonna dig down this possibility in QGIS